# setState() does not assigns value to an array

Tags: reactjs, filter, foreach, setstate

I have a state as follows inside the constructor

```
this.state = {
type: {
            Building: false,
            House : false,
            Plot : false,
            FarmHouse : false,
        },
        location : {
            Lahore : false,
            Islamabad : false,
            Karachi : false,
            Peshawar : false
        },
        clicked : false,
        propertyFound: []
    }
```

I have imported {PropertyData} from another file that has data in the following format

```
export const PropertyData = [
    {   
        id:0,
        propertyType: 
                    "Building",
        location : "Lahore",
        society : "wapdatown",

    },
    {   
        id:1,
        propertyType: 
                    "House",
        location : "Islamabad",
        society : "faisaltown", 
    },
    {   
        id:2,
        propertyType: 
                    "Plot",
        location : "Karachi",
        society : "johartown",
    },
    {   
        id:3,
        propertyType: 
                    "Building",
        location : "Islamabad",
        society : "wapdatown",
    }
      
]
```

Now I wish to filter data from the {PropertyData} according to the user's input. locationValues contains the value of the city which the user has given. findCity() filters data and returns the data which contains location === city entered by the user.

```
findCity(){
        let newArray = [];
        for(let locationValues in this.state.location){
            if(this.state.location[locationValues] === true ){
                newArray = PropertyData.filter(element => 
                    element.location === locationValues   
                )
            }
            this.setState({propertyFound : newArray},() => console.log(this.state.propertyFound));
        }       
    }
```

I console.log(newArray) and it gives me correct values but this.state.propertyFound is empty. Alternatively, I tried another logic.

```
for(let typeValues in this.state.type){
        for(let locationValues in this.state.location){
            if(this.state.type[typeValues] === true  && this.state.location[locationValues] === true){
                PropertyData.forEach((item,index,arr) => {
                    if(arr[index].propertyType === typeValues && arr[index].location === locationValues){
                        // this.setState({
                        // propertyFound : [...this.state.propertyFound,item]
                        //})
                        let newArray;
                        newArray = this.state.propertyFound.push(item);
                        this.setState({propertyFound : newArray});
                    }
                    
                })

            }
        } 
    }
```

This works perfectly fine and gives correct results. Can anyone explain the issue in above logic that I am trying to implement?

Comment: Everything in `this.state.location` is false, so given you only want to add to `newArray` when `this.state.location[locationValues] === true`, I would _expect_ `propertyFound` to be empty. Your second block isn't checking that, and so will act differently.

Comment: I have pasted the complete code. The second block is also checking it and it does become true once I give an input. I have checked everything else. It works fine. @samuei

Comment: Pretty sure `Array.push()` returns the length of the array, so won't `propertyFound` in the second block return an integer? In the first block, it's an array.